# After entering docker, the `/etc/group` is the same with the host one

Tags: linux, docker

After entering the docker, my `/etc/group` is the same as the host one. However, I didn't mount `/` to the docker.

I have tried some machines, some of them have this problem, others not.

docker version is Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056dbc

```sh
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm -it -u root pytorch/pytorch:1.1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7.5-devel bash
```

The expected result is /etc/group is brand new, however, it's the same as the host one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The admin changes the default docker setting.